# "module 'babel' has no attribute 'dates'" when trying to format time and date

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-babel

I have written this function to format time and date in my Flask app with [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/):

```
import babel
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

def format_datetime(value, format='medium'):
    if format == 'full':
        format = "EEEE MMMM, d, y 'at' h:mma"
    elif format == 'medium':
        format = "EE MM, dd, y h:mma"

    print(format)    
    return babel.dates.format_datetime(date, format)

app.jinja_env.filters['datetime'] = format_datetime

strTime = '2021-01-07 12:13:07'
print(format_datetime(strTime))
```

But when I run this it raises this exception:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\timedateTest\timepy.py", line 26, in <module>
     print(format_datetime(strTime))   
    File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\timedateTest\timepy.py", line 18, in format_datetime
     return babel.dates.format_datetime(date, format) AttributeError: module 'babel' has no attribute 'dates'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899198/module-has-no-attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing:

```
import babel
```

to:

```
from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time
```

Comment: received this exception AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'days'

Comment: Or simply `from babel.dates import format_datetime`, as the other two functions are not used.

Comment: @TheTruth If the problem related to importing the function is solved, and now there is another problem, please ask a new question (after researching the new problem yourself first).

Comment: @TheTruth I think this is a problem related to the default locale you set. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/4838056/10895906 which is similar to yours

Answer (score 2):

#### You can make use of the `datetime` module in python.

```
import datetime

def format_datetime(value, format='medium'):

    # Create a python date object to work on
    date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if format == 'full':
        return date_obj.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    elif format == 'medium':
        return date_obj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y, %H:%M:%S")

strTime = '2021-01-07 12:13:07'
```

**Returned formats**

```
# output for format full
'07-January-2021, 12:13:07'

# output for format medium
'07-Jan-2021, 12:13:07'
```

You can plug any kind of format using a string as a parameter for `date_obj.strftime()` method.

Date formats can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp) for reference.

Comment: running your code in an empty neew file shows error `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentatation at http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/dates.html I suspect that passing a string into babel.dates.format_datetime is not allowed as this function expects a datetime:

```
babel.dates.format_datetime(datetime=None, format='medium', tzinfo=None, locale=default_locale('LC_TIME'))
```

- datetime – the datetime object; if None, the current date and time is used
- format – one of “full”, “long”, “medium”, or “short”, or a custom date/time pattern
- tzinfo – the timezone to apply to the time for display
- locale – a Locale object or a locale identifier

Also as John Gardounis mentions using a direct reference might help.
As you define your own format_datetime function for yourself my suggestion is:

```
from babel.dates import format_datetime as babel_format_datetime
```

Then replace this line in your function:

```
return babel.dates.format_datetime(date, format)
```

with:

```
return babel_format_datetime(date, format)
```

Comment: The problem is not how the `format_datetime` is *used*, it is how  it is *imported*.